# aws php sdk - function works on local host and in console, but not on browser when on server

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, command-line, html, aws-cloudformation

I'm having an issue where my php function works when I call it from the server's command line, but not on the web page. It also works on the web page when I have it hosted locally through WAMP.

Any ideas what might be the issue?

```
function getCFTemplateSummary($CFUrl){
//init client
$client = new CloudFormationClient(array(
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region' => 'us-east-1',
    'version' => '2010-05-15',
    'http' => [ 'verify' => false ]
    ));

    try {
    $result = $client->getTemplateSummary(['TemplateURL' => $CFUrl]);
    }catch(\Aws\CloudFormation\Exception\CloudFormationException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }catch(\Aws\Exception\AwsException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    echo "inside the function";
    echo "</pre>";
    return $result;

 }
```

I was able to trace down the issue to this by trial and error commenting ...but not sure how to proceed debugging as I don't see any error messages.

```
$result = $client->getTemplateSummary(['TemplateURL' => $CFUrl]);
```

Comment: what you are trying to do with aws sdk

Comment: eh, trying to automate part of my job testing CFTs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try catching `Exception` instead of `\Aws\CloudFormation\CloudFormationException`, it's possible that a different Exception (e.g., incorrectly configured AWS credentials) is being thrown from your server that you aren't explicitly catching in your current code.

Comment: thank you so much! that provided the error message that showed I had the credentials file in the wrong directory for that user.